# Array Mvc Controller to JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to pass an array from mvc controller to java script  in `HTML.CS` page

This is My Model

```
public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And My Controller

```
public IActionResult Calendar()
{
    ViewData["User"] = user;
    ViewData["Events"] = events;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As it stands it very hard to understand what you're asking and even harder to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

In controller:

```
public IActionResult Calendar()
{
  var users = db.Users;

  var events = db.Events.ToList();
  ViewData["events"] = events; // Send this list to the view

  return View(users .ToList());
}
```

In view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.User>

@{
  var events= (List<Event>) ViewData["events"]; // Cast events to list
}

@foreach (var e in @events) // Print the list
{
  @Html.Label(e.Description);
}

<table>
    ...
    @foreach (var item in Model)  
    {
      ...  // each user in here in item
    }
</table>
```